# How to receive json data from html

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to send some Json data from html to my c# controller. I need it because i want to generate PDF file from this data. I can't find any solution to this problem. Here is how my posting looks:

```
function sendJSONData() {
    var stringToSend = generatePdf();
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: stringToSend,
            dataType: "json",
            success: getSuccess,
            error: getFail
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    };
    function getSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data.Response);
    };
    function getFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    };

}
```

Comment: Where is the url of your Controller in ajax request? I think you missed to put the url in your ajax request.

Comment: You can find more details on [Model binding JSON POSTs in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) and [How to post complex JSON data to server in ASP.NET Core](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-post-complex-JSON-d15bb765).

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet from some of my projects, use as an orientation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(object));

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.cartbadge').html(result.data);

                    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        $('.cartbadge')
                            .animate({ marginTop: '-=' + '10px' }, 100)
                            .animate({ marginTop: '+=' + '10px' }, 100);
                    }

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.default-navbar').load('/Home/ReturnPartialNavbar');
                        $('#cartModalHolder').load('/Home/ReturnPartialCartModal');
                    }, 400);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

You are not specifying an url to your controller. How should your script know where to send your data? ;)